# Shell Script Process Command

Tags: shell

I was trying to find out the ways to create a child process through Shell Script but I couldn't.
I wonder why Shell script command has the command that kills the process but not creates it.

Comment: [Ten seconds in google.](http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-processes.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell has a myriad different ways of creating processes; most of what a shell script does is execute processes.

```
process
process &
process1 | process2
if process1
then process2
else process3
fi
(process)
x=$(process)
```

And so on, ad nauseam.

Comment: I don't understand your code. Could you explain it? Is 'process' a command?

Comment: The first line, `process`, causes the shell to run a process. The second line, `process &`, causes the shell to run a process in the background (without waiting for it to finish). The third line runs two processes, sending the standard output of `process1` to the standard input of `process2`. Each of these has the shell creating processes. ... It may be that I haven't understood your question, but you were asking why the shell can kill processes but can't create them, and I showed examples of ways that the shell _can_ create processes (though it would be hard pressed to kill most of them).